# Equivalence Relation Properties

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, absolute-value

I have to define whether the following relation is symmetric, reflexive, and transitive.

> Define a relation *R* on **Z** as follows: (*x*, *y*) ∈ *R* if and
>   only if *x* = |*y*|:

This is my answer so far:

Is *R* symmetric? No

Is *R* reflexive? No

Is *R* transitive? No

I am not exactly confident with this answer because I am not sure if we should check these properties based on *x*, *y* for all *x*, *y* ∈ *R* or based on *x*, *y* for all *x*, *y* ∈ **Z**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $R$ is defined on $\mathbb Z$, so we assume that $x,y \in \mathbb Z$.

---

You're correct that $R$ is not symmetric:

- Take $x = 3 \in \mathbb Z$ and $y = -3 \in \mathbb Z$. Notice that $3 = |-3|$ but $-3 \neq 3 = |3|$. So $(x,y) \in R$ but $(y,x) \notin R$.

You're correct that $R$ is not reflexive:

- Take $x = -3 \in \mathbb Z$. Notice that $-3 \neq 3 = |-3|$. So $(x,x) \notin R$.

However, $R$ is in fact transitive:

- Choose any $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ such that $(x,y),(y,z) \in R$ so that $x = |y|$ and $y = |z|$. Then by substituting, notice that:
  $$
  x = |y| = ||z|| = |z|
  $$
  So $(x,z) \in R$, as desired.

Comment: As far as I know, picking values for (x,y),(y,z)∈R requires us to pick 3 distinct values for x, y, and z. However, if we want to satisfy the equation x=|y| and y=|z|, we can only choose at the most 2 distinct values. Or it does not matter?

Comment: The three values need not be distinct. Indeed, the identity relation (which only contains ordered pairs of the form $(a,a)$) is transitive.